# Sliding Image in imageView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

i want to create Sliding Image ImageView in android. In that when i
   move finger on Right side than current image move on Right side and
   Next image display. Same thing is done when i move finger
   up,down,Left. I have One Image Array. In that many image are there...
   One By One i want that all image in Slide... I Try many code But Not
   get Proper output... 
   In my Code there are only 1 ImageView
   Can any one Help me.....
   I try this Link also but not got proper help

[sliding between images android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515764/sliding-between-images-android)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you are looking for viewflippers.

These can help you to get started,

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/image-switcher-view-android-developer.html

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/

http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/14/flipping-your-views/

http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/2009/04/16/how-to-implement-swipe-action-in-android/

Sample.

```
<Gallery
      android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Gallery> <ImageSwitcher
      android:id="@+id/ImageSwitcher01"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"> </ImageSwitcher>

iSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.ImageSwitcher01);
            iSwitcher.setFactory(this);
            iSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        android.R.anim.fade_in));
            iSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out));
```

Comment: Thxs For your help....
But i try this all code....
i think u cnt understand my Qus....
i have only One Imageview... and in that imageView image set Dynamicaly ....